Conditional formatting for matching names based on dropdown with dates
I have a table with a list of 100 desks and 14 columns with dates.
In each column I allocate team members for the specific date on top

I've made additional columns with each team's staff members. I want their names to highlight in green based on whether they have been allocated a desk for specific date.
My issue is that the conditional formatting needs to be linked to a dropdown list of dates and the cell to highlight only if a match is found based on the selected date from the dropdown.
Basically D9:D19 should highlight in green if there is a match based on the date in the dropdown menu and highlight removed if no match in selected date
I looked up various forums, but can't find a formula for conditional formatting that us able to LOOKUP the dropdown menu and look for matches based on the selection. My other issue is that the matches should be searched in a range and not specific columns or rows (which is all I found online so far)

You can use https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/ to convert an excel range into a copiable markdown.

If merged cells are used then take care that the dates and names are placed in the same column.
In the conditional formatting the formula is:
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D9,OFFSET(INDEX($A$28:$N$28,1,MATCH($A$26,$A$28:$N$28,0)),0,0,12,1),1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)


I never tried on Data validation source, but I thought ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D9, OFFSET(), 1, FALSE)) can be replaced with OR(D9 = OFFSET())? even in pre-365 excel?

Yes, you are right.
